# Finding Boundary in an image given the points obtained using PSO

Tags: matlab, boundary, particle-swarm

Aim : To detect  boundary in the image using PSO

I have taken an image img , applied PSO ( function used - gradient) and obtained the given result.

The problem with this is that pixels with probable edges are obtained(obvious since the gradient function is used) . I thought of applying threshold to the gradient value obtained for each particle in its 5x5 window centered at the particle itself. This is the result

[image: Result of PSO]

This seems to work fine as long as the original image does not contain any texture. 
But whenever there is a texture like presence in the image, this fails. Can you help me with what can I do with the particles that are obtained after positioning them using the PSO ?

Comment: I proposed an edit to the post to infix your image,  just so that people don't have to follow links. ~